# BASIC Fraction prog., Can anyone tell me whats the problem with this program?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//.........interface section.........
@interface Fraction : NSObject 
{
    int numerator;
    int denomenator;
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenomenator: (int) d;
@end
//.........Implementaion Section........
@implementation Fraction
-(void) print {
    NSLog(@"Solution %i and %i is:",numerator,denomenator);
}
-(void) setNumerator:(int)n
{
    numerator = n;
}
-(void) setDenomenator:(int)d
{
    denomenator = d;
}
@end
//..........Program Section..........
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...

    Fraction *frac1=[[Fraction alloc] init];
    Fraction *frac2=[[Fraction alloc] init];

    //....Set 1.. fraction = 2/3

    [frac1 setNumerator:2];
    [frac2 setDenomenator:3];

    //.....Set 2 .. Fraction = 3/9

    [frac1 setNumerator:3];
    [frac2 setDenomenator:9];

    //...... Display Function.....

    NSLog(@"First Fraction is:");
    [frac1 print];

    NSLog(@"Second Fraction is:");
    [frac2 print];

    [frac1 release];
    [frac2 release];

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
```

The output I'm getting is not displaying the "answer in fraction" i.e 2/3 and 3/9

Comment: The output is what you pass to NSLog in `print` method... What did you expect to?

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
[frac1 setNumerator:2];
[frac2 setDenomenator:3];
```

instead of this

```
[frac1 setNumerator:2];
[frac1 setDenomenator:3];
```

you have done the same for frac2

Comment: I tried this and got:  [Switching to process 469 thread 0x0]
2011-07-23 18:50:25.159 3[469:707] First Fraction is:
2011-07-23 18:50:25.162 3[469:707] Solution 2 and 3 is: {// I want "2/3" here..}
2011-07-23 18:50:25.162 3[469:707] Second Fraction is:
2011-07-23 18:50:25.163 3[469:707] Solution 3 and 9 is: {// I want "3/9" here..}
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: You just need to change the Fraction print method function from NSLog(@"Solution %i and %i is:",numerator,denominator); to printf("%d/%d",numerator,denominator); using c's printf instead of NSLog will remove all of that addition debug info, just remember that printf does not support Objective-C "%@" to print objects so if you want to print out a string object with printf you will have to do something like [aStr UTF8String] and then output that with %s.